# Make a LINQ query dynamic to bring back all rows or only rows with a link to a lookup table?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have a query that returns a list of currencies and joins to a lookup table. The result is then put into a class object (which works fine):

```
 var queryforobject = from x in db.CurrencyExchangeRates.AsNoTracking()
                      join c in db.CurrencyTypes.AsNoTracking() on x.CurrencyTypeID equals c.ID
                      orderby x.ID
                      select new CurrencyExchangeRateObject 
                      { 
                          ID = x.ID, 
                          CurrencyID = c.ID, 
                          Currency = c.Description, 
                          ExchangeRate = x.ExchangeRate, 
                          LastEditedDate = x.LastEditedDate, 
                          LastEditedBy = x.LastEditedBy, 
                          Active = x.Active 
                      };
```

I want to make this more dynamic, so if no `CurrencyTypeID` is supplied then it will return the full list (as it does already) - otherwise if a `CurrencyTypeID` is supplied it will only show where `X.CurrencyTypeID = ID`.

Something along the lines of an inline if?

Answer (score 1):

There are a few options for filtering the query based on CurrencyTypeID if a search value (named `currencyTypeID` in this answer) is supplied, but return all data if no `currencyTypeID` is supplied.

First option: You could add a where clause to your existing query expression. The WHERE clause below will return every record in the data set if `null` is passed in for the `currencyTypeID` variable, otherwise it will filter the results.

```
from x in db.CurrencyExchangeRates.AsNoTracking()
     join c in db.CurrencyTypes.AsNoTracking() on x.CurrencyTypeID equals c.ID
     where (currencyTypeID == null || x.CurrencyTypeID == currencyTypeID)
     orderby x.ID

select new CurrencyExchangeRateObject { 
       ID = x.ID, 
       CurrencyID = c.ID, 
       Currency = c.Description, 
       ExchangeRate = x.ExchangeRate, 
       LastEditedDate = x.LastEditedDate, 
       LastEditedBy = x.LastEditedBy, 
       Active = x.Active
     };
```

Alternatively: Since `queryforobject` is of type `IQueryable<T>`, you can use LINQ's fluent API to append a WHERE clause to the query inside an `if` statement. You need to be more careful about timing on this one though as it needs to be done before you force evaluation of the `IQueryable` with a `foreach` loop, `.ToList()`, `.Select()` or other LINQ methods that force evaluation.

```
if(currencyTypeID != null)
    queryforobject  = queryforobject.Where(cerObj => cerObj.CurrencyID == currencyTypeID);
```

Comment: Thanks for that. CurrencyTypeID is actually initialised to -1, so the currencyTypeID will either be -1 (for bringing back all) or a value of 1 or above where a CurrencyTypeID was supplied.